# Dynamically GoToState return false

Tags: c#, wpf

i created the simplest WPF/c# application with Visual Studio 2012.
i want to create an interface to edit an sqlite table (with 1 and 0 values). To do this the application generates some ToggleButton on WrapPanel, this one should be checked and at State Selected.
but GoToState returns false on each ToggleButtonon generation, whereas GoToState on btn.Click works.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds_Macrolist_C.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton btn3 = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton();

    btn3.Template = (ControlTemplate)System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource("Template_8");

    p_zone.Children.Add(btn3);

    var states = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this);

    bool shouldReturnTrue = VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this, "Selected", true);

    btn3.Click += (s, ee) =>
    {
        if (btn3.IsChecked == true)
        {
            bool success2 = VisualStateManager.GoToState(btn3, "UnSelected", true);

            //rest of code
        }
    };
```

WPF template:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectGroupe">
        <VisualState x:Name="UnSelected"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                    Duration="0:0:0.001" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame Value="#FFC80008"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
```

What is wrong, and how can i fix it?

Comment: just to make things clear for me. you create ToggleButton and they don't  represent the state which is already in the database right?

Comment: Why are you doing `GoToElementState(this...`? What's `this` in that context? I assume it's not the ToggleButton, of course. So if you are trying to change the ToggleButton visual state, it's obviously not gonna work - Though, I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to change the faulty line for:

```
bool shouldReturnTrue = VisualStateManager.GoToState(btn3, "Selected", true);
```

You were using `this` instead of passing the ToggleButton, and I'd say that `GoToState` is the correct method to call here.

Anyway, chances are this won't work anyway. For this to work, you need the control to have a ControlTemplate with a working VisualStateManager. In your code, you've just added the ControlTemplate, but the control is still not loaded or rendered, including its VisualStateManager.

What happens if you do this?

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds_Macrolist_C.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton btn3 = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton();

    btn3.Template = (ControlTemplate)System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource("Template_8");

    p_zone.Children.Add(btn3);

    var states = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this);

    btn3.Loaded += Button_Loaded;

    btn3.Click += (s, ee) =>
    {
        if (btn3.IsChecked == true)
        {
            bool success2 = VisualStateManager.GoToState(btn3, "UnSelected", true);

            //rest of code
        }
    };

}

private void Button_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton;

    button.Loaded -= Button_Loaded;
    bool shouldReturnTrue = VisualStateManager.GoToState(button, "Selected", true);
}
```